# Can the cop catch the thief?

Tags: mathematics, story, strategy, pursuit-evasion

The cop and the thief, both mathematical points, live in an open interval $(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}$. That is, their universe is a line segment of length 1 without the 2 endpoints. We know that both move simultaneously and continuously at a maximum speed of 1. Both react instantaneously according to their respective positions. At time 0, the thief and the cop are at positions 1/3 and 2/3 respectively. The cop catches the thief if cop position=thief position.

**Here's arguments from both sides, can you decide who's right?**

**Thief:** Hmmm, let me see, at time t the cop is at position $C_t$, but I'm always able to keep my position at $\frac{C_t}{2}$, therefore my position never coincide with that of the cop, therefore he can never catch me :)

**Cop:** That's nonsense! All I need to do is keep moving towards 0 at full speed until my position coincide with the thief's, and this will happen very soon :)

Note that a "strategy" for both cop and thief *must* be defined as a function of x over time.

Comment: Reminds me of Zeno's paradoxes. I find the thief's argument unconvincing but can't quite formalize why.

Comment: Does this puzzle have an answer?

Comment: Thief is right as explained several times below: meeting point is missing (using thief strategy). I would not really call this **undefined**.

Comment: @FirstNameLastName If you don't think it's undefined, explain to me exactly what happens at t=2/3?

Comment: @DJClayworth : thanks for letting me think twice. Either party (cop thief) can claim whatever is necessarily not valid at t=2/3.

Comment: I don't have the reputation for it, but I would vote "close, move to math.SE"

Comment: @Jeffrey Where it would be promptly closed as "off-topic", I'm sure ;)

Comment: @FirstNameLastName "Either party can claim whatever is necessarily not valid at t=2/3" What does that mean? What happens at t=2/3?

Comment: @DJClayworth : sorry to not be exact, basically, I mow agree it's undefined. I can't tell happens at t=2/3 :-)

Comment: Yeah this question is not very good...

Comment: @BioPhysicist I think it's a great question, and really interesting, even if it's not completely specified. Discovering it wasn't completely specified was good fun.

Comment: @DJClayworth Of course. I didn't say it isn't interesting or not fun to think about. Sorry for not being specific.

Comment: After all this work, I can now say with confidence, "This is not a puzzle. What happens on encountering the edge of the universe is missing vital information."

Comment: @Eric, there seems to be lots of disagreement in the comments in the answers with the formal definition of a strategy. Can you clarify?

Comment: @justhalf Many answers have the correct definition of strategies, such as isaacg's.

Comment: Thanks, so to clarify, the cop's strategy `c(t)` means the position of the cop at time t?

Comment: @justhalf yes...

Comment: @Eric If that is the definition of a strategy that you are looking for then please edit that into the question. Different definitions of strategies do produce different results. While you are about it you could clarify the question of whether the players are actually forbidden the x=0 position or if it is merely "out of the universe". And whether "strategies" are expected to be over the whole time interval, or if it is acceptable to define a strategy for t<2/3 knowing that it will be impossible to continue it after that time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fundamentally, the issue is that

1. For every fixed cop strategy, there exists a thief strategy that beats it.
2. For every fixed thief strategy, there exists a cop strategy that beats it.

For an easier picture, this is effectively what the game looks like:

1. Cop chooses a real number $C\in(0,1)$ (basically $\liminf_{t\in\mathbb{R}^+} C(t)$ of their position)
2. Thief chooses a real number $T\in(0,1)$
3. Cop wins if $C\leq T$

Who wins? **Neither side has a winning strategy.** [Games without a value are not controversial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_without_a_value), and can occur whenever players have infinite strategy spaces.

Here, this is because the space is not [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space), so neither can pick "$0$", the limiting strategy, *which isn't a strategy at all*. Having a limit which does not exist in the original space is not controversial. "What's the smallest strictly positive real number?" *has no answer at all*.

Both sides may, of course, pick a strategy that goes to $0$ in the limit $t\rightarrow\infty$. This doesn't change the issue, of course: the players duel on *how fast* they approach 0, and any fixed choice by either one can always be beat by the other.

When considered as one side having to move first, [that player loses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_game).

---

*Previous longer answer*

Question is **undefined** for another reason: this whole "react instantaneously to the other" condition causes mutual self-reference, and we all know [just](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox) [how](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) [many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox) [problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interesting_number_paradox) [come](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Bernays_paradox) [from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knower_paradox) [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newcomb%27s_paradox).

The space is not [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space), and therefore, so is the space of strategies. It shouldn't be surprising that a definable strategy which definitively wins the game simply *does not exist*. The proof ends up as:

1. For every fixed cop strategy, there exists a thief strategy that beats it.
2. For every fixed thief strategy, there exists a cop strategy that beats it.

Therefore, strategy mutual induction goes nuclear, that is, the limit does not exist and no unbeatable strategy exists for either side. The answer **critically** depends on who has to blink first, i.e. determine their strategy at time $t=2/3$ first. They lose.

---

Unimportant complications: If both are allowed to basically "update" their strategy upon seeing the other's current choice, they both never end, in [Zeno's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes). *Therefore this process generates no answer at all*, i.e. the problem is undefined.

Loosening this a little, suppose $C(t)$ is the cop's (possibly to-be-determined) strategy, and $T(t)$ is the thief's. Letting them "react" presumably means that $C(t+\epsilon)$ can depend on $T(t)$ and vice versa.

Essentially, once the cop sees the thief at time $t$, they decide their strategy for the next $\epsilon$ time, **without seeing the thief between $t$ and $t+\epsilon$**. Or, the thief has to decide first for time $(t,t+\epsilon]$ without seeing the cop.

At some point, one of the sides has to blink and decide their position at $t=2/3$, if $\epsilon$ cannot be arbitrarily small. They are forced to turn back (or stop moving) and lose.

The other choice, that both sides may end up publishing arbitrarily small further strategy choices, leads to Zeno's paradox in that you *can't* validly obtain any result that extends to or past $t=2/3$, as both keep playing chicken and nobody states their position at $t=2/3$ exactly.

Proof the cop wins if the thief is the one forced to hit $t=2/3$:

1. Cop keeps moving at full speed before $t=2/3$.
2. At some finite step $t_n<2/3$, the thief has to choose through $T(t_{n+1})$ for $t_{n+1}\geq2/3$.
3. They can't pick $T(t)$ to keep moving forwards, that is, $$\liminf_{t\rightarrow t_{n+1}}T(t)=L>0$$
4. Cop overtakes $L$ and wins.

Proof the thief wins if the cop is the one forced to hit $t=2/3$:

1. Same as above, cop has to turn back at some point, so
   $$\liminf_{t\rightarrow t_{n+1}}C(t)=L>0$$
2. Thief forever stays just in front of the cop, one particular strategy is $T(t)=C(t)/2$.

The above presumes the cop or the thief is the one that is always forced to choose first, at least around time $t=2/3$.

The actual condition is: if the thief is forced to choose first for any strictly positive amount of time at or after $t=2/3$, they lose. The cop arranges things so that in that specific time interval they are stopped by the universe boundaries, again having to turn back at a finite point.

Comment: To make the answer stronger: For every pair of current positions $0 < T(t_0) < C(t_0) < 1$, any strategy continuing from that position can be beat by some strategy of the other player. This shows that they don't need knowledge of the other's future actions.

Comment: And in the early simplification, we could have $\liminf_{t \in \mathbb{R}^+} C(t) = 0$. Rather than try to rationalize that case separately, we do have $\inf_{t \in [0,2/3]} C(t) > 0$, or on any fixed interval $[0,T]$ where $T \geq \frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Who said the cop or thief have to "choose a real number"? They can both just "move left at full speed". I don't have to choose a real number to start walking. Assuming they have to choose a destination first and letting their movement be constrained by that choice is to inherently assume the absurd conclusion of Zeno's paradox.

Comment: @Shufflepants It can be revised to see that they are not choosing positions, but choosing a continuous function that maps from time [0,inf) to a position (0,1) (that agrees with the past movements, etc etc). You can view it as keep changing function if you like, but the resulting trajectory is still a function at the end.

Comment: @justhalf exactly - the number they choose is "how close to zero they ever get", which is a simple summary of their strategy

Comment: @justhalf That's not how moving with a constant velocity works. One's "strategy" can just be "move left at speed 1" without any necessity to specify a mapping from t:[0,inf) to d:(0,1). If "move left at speed 1" leads to a discontinuity at t=1/3, then it's up to the OP to decide what happens in that case or to conclude that the cop cannot catch the thief because at t=1/3, the physics stop being well defined. It's just like what happens when something falls into a black hole and hits the singularity. It's perfectly valid to just fall in, but our current model breaks at that point.

Comment: @Shufflepants I think we just have to agree to disagree. Since you touch about singularity in black hole, which is something that cannot be explained intuitively, I think we are simply at an en passe here.

Comment: @Shufflepants "We know that both move simultaneously and **continuously** at a maximum speed of 1." "This leads to a discontinuity at t=1/3." The conclusion, of course, is that *this is not a valid strategy*.

Answer (score 21):

**It's undefined** although a slight tightening up of the question would make it defined.

What the question lacks is a specification of what happens when a player reaches the limit of the universe. To be more specific:

> Suppose each player executes their optimum strategy of moving at maximum speed in the negative direction. What exactly happens at $t=1/3$ when the thief reaches the end of the universe<sup>1</sup>?

Note that you can't avoid the question. $t=1/3$ will happen, typically 1/3 of a time unit after the start. If you try to pretend it won't then you do end up with Zeno's paradox.

The simplest answer is "they are then outside the boundaries of the universe". Nothing wrong with that. It happens on Star Trek most weeks.

Then the question is answerable with a simple change, which is to make the question "Can the cop catch the thief within the boundaries of the universe?" and of course the answer is

> **No**, thanks to the above optimal strategies. They move in the negative direction at the same speed and never intersect. You can also use the strategies described in several other answers, in which the thief moves at half the speed of the cop, and means they arrive at the boundary of the universe at the same time. The answer is still that the cop catches the thief, but cannot do so inside the limits of the universe. Note that with this condition the thief has not need of a 'complex' strategy like moving at half the speed of the cop. The thief can simply move at full speed in the negative direction, exit the universe, and be immune from capture.

If you want any other answer to the question, you need to say what happens at $t=1/3$ in some other way. Specifically what position does the thief occupy at $t=1/3$ if they move at speed -1 for all that time? Do they stop before the edge? If so how far before the edge? In physics terms you have to say what happens "close to" the edge of the universe. Real life "unreachable points" all exist because the behaviour near those points prevents them from being reached, not because they are arbitrarily "forbidden"<sup>2</sup>.

One of the arguments used elsewhere it "the thief (and/or cop) must slow down before he reaches the edge of the universe". Really? Who says? It's not in the question statement. And if they have to slow down, how long before? What happens if they don't? Is there a cop who comes after them and...oh, wait. Answering those questions would make the question determinate.

To make it more mathematically clear that neither cop nor thief "need to slow down" before $x=0$: for all $x$ where $x>0$ there is an $x_1$ which is less than $x$ but also greater than zero. Therefore at any position $x>0$ both cop and thief can move closer to zero. If they can move closer then they can do it at full speed (it just takes less time to get there than if they do it slowly). Hence neither cop nor thief need to slow down *before* the end of the universe.

The confusion is that the question uses the word "universe" which we take to mean "everything". If we used a word like "valid range" or "domain", it would be much easier to make the statement that

> the cop

> cannot

> catch the thief within the valid range".

**Some comments on other answers**
Some answers are saying that the problem is undefined because the strategies of  the two players depend on them simultaneously reacting to each other, or to each other's predicted moves. This is not the case. The optimal strategy for the cop is to move towards x=0 at full speed. It doesn't matter what the thief does, there is no better strategy for the cop. (The thief can make things easier by choosing a worse strategy, but however much worse the thief plays the cop cannot improve on this strategy). Likewise the thief can avoid capture up until $t=2/3$ by moving at half speed towards $x=0$, no matter what the cop does. If the cop plays worse the thief can delay the "point of uncertainty" (the time they reach the end of the universe) by always moving at $p_t/p_c$ towards zero, where $p_t$ is his own position and $p_c$ is the cop's position. No ability to predict the others moves is necessary, and there is no self-reference. It is specifically stated in the question that both players have the ability to instantaneously act out a strategy based on their own and the opponents *position*.

Some answers assume that the strategy for each player involves choosing a position that they move to. I don't believe that is the case, and nothing is said in the question that requires it. Also strategies are instantaneous. You only have to choose a strategy at a specific point in time. So a valid strategy might be "always choose to move left at full speed". There is nothing in the question that makes that an invalid strategy. It's true that if you forbid $x=0$ to the players you can't make that choice at $x=0$, but they can make it at every other point. And the players cannot exist at $x=0$, so it's irrelevant what strategy they are allowed to choose there.

If the players were forced to choose a "stop distance", they still reach that at a finite time, and there is nothing to stop them choosing "another" stop point immediately after that. Say the cop chooses to stop at $x=0.1$ and the thief at $x=0.05$. Can the cop not choose then to move to $x-0.01$? And then even closer the next time?

Footnotes

1. *Apart of course from him eating a fine meal at Milliways.*
2. *Alternative answers taken from scientific and scifi literature might include the player re-entering the universe at the same point from the other direction, or re-entering it from the other end in the same direction. Although strictly nether of those answer the question of what happens at exactly $t=1/3$.*

Comment: Good one, although I disagree with it being based on trying to exit the universe; it's based on attempting to define what "reacting to each other" means by $t=2/3$.

Comment: I don't think interacting makes much difference. The cop has an optimal strategy to move towards the thief at full speed. The thief has an optimal strategy to move away from the cop at something between full speed and half speed. Neither depends on what the other does.

Comment: These "optimal" strategies are functions whose domain does not include $t=2/3$. If your definition of "strategy" is $f:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow(0,1)$, *these don't qualify as strategies in the first place* which is the entire problem.

Comment: I disagree. The strategy can be stated, and the fact that it has an unknown effect at t=1/3 is a problem with the domain definition, not the strategy.

Comment: Where is the thief at time $t=2/3$ when following the supposed strategy? Where is the cop at time $t=2/3$ when following the supposed strategy? Just because you can write down "$f(t)=1/t$" as a definition doesn't mean $f(0)$ is **defined**. The reciprocal is nondifferentiable, discontinuous, *does not exist* at $t=0$. This is **not** a function over the reals.

Comment: @obscurans The strategy is absolutely valid and is a function over the reals. The strategy is defined in terms of speeds, and the thief strategy is "move left at half speed". That is absolutely well defined, for all values of x and for all values of t. The issue is that the strategy takes the thief "outside the bounds of the universe", and the universe (i.e. the question) should define what happens when the thief (or cop) reaches the boundary of the universe.

Comment: Dear DJC, I think obscurans is right. There's no problem to define an open interval as universe (domain). c(t) and w(t) always remain in the universe (0,1) for any t. This is premise from which all other analysis follows. Under the proposed strategies, no matter where the cop and thief are at t=2/3, there will be discontinuity in their trajectories. Hence the proposed strategies are not legitimate. It's the strategies that are ill-defined, not the universe.

Comment: There is no problem with executing the strategy at every time and place before t=2/3. At t=2/3 then you need to decide the positions before you decide if the strategies are decidable, so "the strategies are not valid" is just a consequence of "the positions are not valid". If you allow "exiting the universe" then then neither the strategies nor the positions are a problem.

Comment: Also the problem says "continuously", which has a specific mathematical meaning where the stated or implied codomain or "universe" is part of the meaning. And here "moving at constant speed as long as possible" is not continuous movement.

Comment: @aschepler I think that merely underlines the need for a specification of what happens at t=1/3

Comment: I guess you might say "defining/selecting a strategy" is strange. Most of us take it to mean a function from time to position with bounded speeds. From that point of view, moving at constant velocity for a long time is just not a possibility, since there is no such function. In a regular unbounded $\mathbb{R}^n$-like universe, any continuous (or continuous almost everywhere) velocity function gives a valid position function $\vec x(t) = \vec x(0) + \int_0^t v(\tau)\, d\tau$. But in the interval universe, that same formula is not integrable....

Comment: So a point-person can choose a maximum velocity at any time for any sufficiently short period of time, but can't choose to keep doing that for a longer finite time - which yes, doesn't make sense, but sometimes that's imaginary mathematical universes for you.

Comment: I agree that if choosing a strategy requires choosing a point to move to then you might end up with an endless series of steps where the thief manages to stay ahead of the cop. But nothing in the question says you have to choose a destination point. And even if you could, a strategy that continuously chooses a point within the universe and closer to x=0 than you are results in smaller and smaller timesteps, which converge before x=2/3. That infinite sequence of timesteps does not change the fact that the time t=2/3 will in fact arrive, nor settle the question of what happens when it does.

Comment: @Eric If the thief hits a baseball in the negative direction at a speed of 2. Where is the baseball at t=1/6? Seems you're refusing to accept the singularities in your system by allowing motion at constant speed, but restricted domain. Compare you situation with other singularities in physics such as two point particles under newtonian gravity reaching infinite speed in finite time. Or a single point particle being able to *reach* infinite distance in finite time https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13184/can-an-object-accelerate-to-infinite-speed-in-a-finite-time-interval-in-non-rela

Comment: I've done something very weird here, and written a separate answer to attack a different aspect of the problem. Right now it's got zero votes. Feel free to give feedback.

Comment: I encountered a definition of encountering the end of the universe at speed resulted in impacting on it like a solid wall.

Comment: @DJClayworth, btw I just noticed your comment "The strategy can be stated, and the fact that it has an unknown effect at t=1/3 is a problem with the domain definition, not the strategy." Consider this example: let say the question is changed so that the domain is [0,1] instead of (0,1). Is the strategy that says the cop keep moving left at speed 1 until time t=1 a valid strategy? If so, why? If not, why makes it a valid strategy in (0,1)?

Comment: Both are valid strategies. In fact the strategy is "keep moving left". If the rules of the universe prevent a player from reaching x=0 it should be state by the rules of the universe what happens when they try. Otherwise it becomes "can the cop catch the thief without exiting the range 0 < x < 1" which is not the same thing. I describe this in my first spoiler block. The cop can catch the thief, but only outside the bounds of the universe. Or the cop can have as a strategy "x= 2/3 - t for 0 <= t < 2/3". That's valid.

Comment: ["can the cop catch the thief without exiting the range 0 < x < 1" which is not the same thing.] Nice, this is progress, I think, since I guess this is where we differ. Can you explain more why this is not the same as stating that the universe is (0,1) (which means nobody can exit the range 0 < x < 1)?

Answer (score 11):

> The thief

is right, basically because

> the endpoints are not included.

The problem with one of the two suggested approaches is that

> the cop predicts a definite point of convergence, since the thief has a finite amount of space in which to manoeuvre, but what if the predicted convergence is at the endpoint $0$ or beyond? That means it will actually never be reached. The cop *cannot* continue moving at speed one for time $2/3$ or longer.

The space in which they're moving is sort of like a 1-dimensional [hyperbolic space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_space): they can get infinitesimally close to the boundary but they can never actually reach it.

**TL;DR:** it seems that, on an *open* line segment, Zeno's paradox is actually true.

Comment: Dear Rand, the problem is fully defined. The thief can't move leftward at speed 1 for $\Delta t=1/3$ any more than he can do that for $\Delta t=100$, because both take him out of the domain of the universe.

Comment: Great point, Rand al'Thor, about Zeno's paradox being true in certain circumstances.  I've been casually laughing it off for millennia.  And nice twist, @Eric, to have the interval open.

Comment: OK @Eric, I edited. I think hyperbolic space is a valid way of thinking about this problem? In terms of the way they can move, at least.

Comment: It's true the cop cannot continue moving at speed one for time 2/3 or longer. But it's also true that the thief cannot continue moving at speed 1/2 for time 2/3 or longer. Yet the world doesn't end at time 2/3. Where's the thief at time 2/3? Where is he at time 100?

Comment: @Eric Well, if they both follow their strategies, the cop will be somewhere very close to 0 (having had to slow down below his speed of 1 as he gets too close) and the thief will be twice as close to 0.

Comment: Really? The cop has no reason to slow down before he catches the thief.

Comment: @Eric So the cop doesn't need to slow down, BUT the thief does?

Comment: @SteveV  All I said was the thief cannot continue moving at speed 1/2 for time 2/3 or longer.

Comment: @SteveV And the cop has no reason to slow down before he catches the thief.

Comment: It isn't really defined what would happen if the cop *tried* to move past the edge of the universe. Since there's no minimal position, they can't just run into a wall that would stop their motion there. Normally they would be stopped at some finite distance from the wall because they have size, but here they are just points. If they both die when going off the edge, then the cop could force a mutual death upon them.

Comment: As I say in my answer, the question lacks a statement about what happens at t=2/3?

Comment: @Namaskaram Fixed, thanks! It seems this question is generating a whole lot of disagreeing answers - it's the Monty Hall of open interval chases :-) One of my favourite answers here is [aschepler's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/112377/5373), which uses a more detailed mathematical argument to come to essentially the same conclusion as me.

Comment: Your one-line TL;DR of this one puzzling.se question is now for me important scientific documentation!

Comment: Note that aschepler's answer, which you think highly of, now comes to a different conclusion from you.

Comment: I'll note that the problem was presented in the reals, not the hyperreals.  As the reals do not have infinitesimals, I'm not sure "they can get infinitesimally close to the boundary but they can never actually reach it." actually makes sense.

Comment: A normal interpretation is "for every position there is a position closer to the boundary that that one". This does not need the hyperreals.

Answer (score 11):

Cleaned up answer:

> The problem is not well defined.

To make things concrete, let's say that the cop's strategy is represented as a function c(t), which is dependent on the thief's trajectory w(t), and vice-versa.

The cop's strategy is `c(t) = max(2/3-t, w(t))`. The thief's strategy is `w(t) = c(t)/2`.

Now we can observe for the cop's strategy that

> c(t) will be continuous if w(t) is continuous, because the maximum of two continuous trajectories is continuous.

We can also observe for the thief's strategy that

> w(t) will be continuous if c(t) is continuous, because half of a continuous trajectory is continuous.

But there's a problem:

> The only mutually consistent pair of trajectories for those two strategies over the interval [0, 2/3) is c(t)=2/3-t, w(t)=1/3-t/2. Each of these trajectories cannot be extended to continuous trajectories over the interval [0, 2/3].

So what we have discovered is that

> The requirements "c(t) is continuous if w(t) is continuous" and "w(t) is continuous if c(t) is continuous" are not sufficient to make c(t) and w(t) actually continuous and well-defined. So the problem is not well-defined as a whole.

Is one player right and one player wrong?

> No, I don't think so. I don't think there's a reasonable rule that says that one of these strategies is illegal and the other is legal. They're quite symmetrical. This has revealed that "players react instantaneously to each other" doesn't work well on this sort of universe - a pair of strategies can seem valid, but produce non-well-defined results. As a result, I think the problem itself is not well-defined.

---

Earlier thoughts

One answer is that

> The cop is wrong.

But why is this player's argument wrong?

> The cop's answer is wrong because the cop's proposed movement of "Keep moving towards 0 at full speed" is only well-defined on the interval of time $t \in [0, 2/3)$.

On and after time 2/3,

> the cop has not yet specified how they will move, but it can't simply be "Move at full speed towards 0", or else the cop will leave their universe at time 2/3, which is not allowed.

That being said, there's a bigger problem.

> The cop's movement is required to be continuous. If on the interval of time [0, 2/3), the cop moves at maximum speed towards 0, the cop's movement cannot be continuous over a longer time interval, such as [0, 2/3]. This is impossible because the limit point of the cop's movement over the interval [0, 2/3) is 0, which is not in the universe.

Therefore, we may conclude that

> In order for the cop's movement to be continuous, they cannot move towards 0 at maximum rate until they catch the thief. That does not generate a legal trajectory for the cop, under the thief's proposed response.

But does this problem apply both ways?

> If the cop takes this "inevitably discontinuous trajectory" of moving towards 0 at maximum rate, then the thief will also take an "inevitably discontinuous trajectory", also moving towards 0 with constant rate. The cop could argue that they aren't moving towards 0 forever, merely until the thief diverges from its trajectory, and the thief is required to diverge from that trajectory to maintain continuity.

In the end I think the problem is

> Not well defined, because of the interaction between "continuous movement" and "react instantaneously". In particular, both points can be thought of as moving in a fashion that would react according to a continuous trajectory, given any continuous trajectory of the other point. This is not sufficient to produce continuous trajectories, as we see here. It's not clear how to give a tighter requirement on how a point must react to the other point's movement, which would eliminate this possibility.

One way to try to fix this would be to require that

> If one point moves continuously over some interval [0, a), then the other point must react in such a way that guarantees continuity over the interval [0, a].

In this case,

> Both proposed reactive trajectories are illegal, so both arguments are wrong. I do not know who actually wins in this case.

Comment: Oh 0 is just a marker here. The cop might have said "keeping moving leftward" until he catches the thief. This can easily be made rigorous: formally, let w(t) be the thief's trajectory, then the cop's strategy is c(t)=max(2/3-t, w(t)).

Comment: @Eric That strategy results in a continuous trajectory given a continuous trajectory from the thief. Likewise, the thief's strategy results in a continuous trajectory given a continuous trajectory from the cop. But paired together, both strategies result in discontinuous trajectories.

Comment: Movements are **required** to be continuous. Where does discontinuity come from?

Comment: The thief can move at half the speed of any *actual* cop movement. It doesn't matter that the cop initially has a plan which isn't possible to execute.

Comment: @Eric For any thief's trajectory w(t) that is continuous, the cop's strategy c(t)=max(2/3-t, w(t)) will also be continuous. For any cop trajectory c(t) that is continuous, the thief's strategy w(t)=c(t)/2 will also be continuous. But the only mutually consistent pair of trajectories for those two strategies over the interval [0, 2/3) is c(t)=2/3-t, w(t)=1/3-t/2. Each of these trajectories cannot be extended to continuous trajectories over the interval [0, 2/3]. I don't think there's a reasonable rule that says that one of these strategies is illegal and the other is legal.

Comment: So the proposed strategies can't both be true over the time interval [0,2/3), and we can't determine which one isn't. I completely agree. I think this basically concludes the problem.

Comment: But then you can't say the cop's argument is wrong any more than you can say the thief's is.

Comment: This is a better way than mine of demonstrating that the problem is not well defined.

Comment: @Eric I think you're right. The strategies can't both work simultaneously, but neither is more wrong than the other.

Comment: No, "react instantaneously" is not the culprit. Let's turn off the light in this universe so neither one can see the other. In this case they can't react at all, but you still can't decide who wins, can you? ;-)

Comment: The cop does not need a strategy that depends on the thief's position or velocity. "Move left at maximum speed" is a valid strategy at all places in the universe.

Answer (score 6):

The number line’s origin’s being excluded means that . . .

> . . . the thief will elude the cop.

It also means that the maximum speeds of both cop and thief . . .

> . . . are immaterial after *almost* the first 1/3 unit of time
>  when the thief can be infinitesimally close to the origin.
>
>  Upon that, the thief can relax in place until the cop reaches
>  twice as far from the origin.
>
>  After that, the thief may indeed forever attain
>  positions halfway between the origin and the cop
>  by merely approaching the origin at half of
>  whatever speed the cop assumes.

Comment: Ho humn, fancy meeting you here :-)

Comment: No, the thief cannot remain *forever* at halfway between the cop and the origin. They can remain at halfway between the cop and the origin for *whatever position the cop  occupies*, but that isn't forever.

Comment: Dear @DJClayworth, my solution pleads a diagram.  As mentioned in other solutions, forever is the only option as neither cop nor thief can maintain full speed to their destinations.

Comment: @humn No. If you say the thief occupies a position halfway between the end of the universe and the cop "forever", then please tell me where that position is at t=2/3? t=2/3 is a valid time that will happen. You must be able to define their positions at that time, or you cannot say they will be like that "forever".

Comment: @DJClayworth , i seriously take feedback and will review all solutions, especially yours, and edit my post.  Please stay tuned.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: I don't know!

> The thief can evade the cop.

Let's call the thief's position as a function of time $\Theta(t)$, and the cop's position as a function of time $C(t)$. We know each function is continuous. We don't know if they're differentiable, but based on the maximum speed restriction we can say $|\Theta(b)-\Theta(a)| < b-a$ and $|C(b)-C(a)| < b-a$ for any two times $a<b$.

One important thing to note: The point-people are described as able to react instantly according to their "positions". But because of that same instant reaction, neither can assume any knowledge about how the other will move in the future.

The cop's strategy of "move at full speed until our positions coincide" ($C(t) = \max(\frac{2}{3}-t, \Theta(t))$) is not a valid strategy because it depends on the movement of the thief in the future. The cop can't move left at full speed until an unknown time any more than move left at full speed for a full second.

Also, a thief's strategy of "move at half the speed of the cop" ($\Theta'(t) = C'(t)$) is not valid, since speed is a derivative involving a prediction into the future and is not really based on the cop's current position.

But the thief does still have a valid strategy using only current positions as input: Label the "Zeno points" $Z_n = 2^{-n}: \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \ldots.$ Whenever the thief is between Zeno points, the thief will move left at speed 1 until the next Zeno point. When a thief is at a Zeno point $Z_n$ and the cop is to the right of $Z_{n-1}$, the thief stands still. When the thief is at a Zeno point $Z_n$ and the cop is at or to the left of Zeno point $Z_{n-1}$, the thief moves left at speed 1. That is,

$$ \Theta'(t) = \begin{cases}
0 & \exists n: \Theta(t)=2^{-n} \mathrm{\ and\ } C(t)>2^{1-n} \\
-1 & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

This is a valid strategy only if for every $T \geq 0$,
$$\Theta(0) + \int_0^T \Theta'(t)\, dt \in (0,1)$$

(including the requirement that $\Theta'$ is integrable in the first place.)

Given any continuous $C(t): [0, \infty) \to (0,1)$, we can show by induction  that when the cop arrives at any Zeno point for the first time, the thief's strategy so far is valid, the thief is currently at the next Zeno point, and the thief has not yet been caught.

The initial thief movement, after integration, is $\Theta(t) = \frac{1}{3} - t$ for $0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{12}$ to reach $\Theta(t) = Z_2 = \frac{1}{4}$ at time $\frac{1}{12}$. When $t < \frac{1}{12}$, $C(t) > C(0) - \frac{1}{12} = \frac{7}{12} > Z_1$. Since $\Theta(t) < \frac{1}{3} < Z_1$ during this entire time, the thief was not caught during the first $\frac{1}{12}$ second. So if the cop reaches $Z_1$ for the first time (if ever) at time $t_1$, $t_1 > \frac{1}{12}$, the thief is already at $\Theta(t_1) = Z_2$ and has still not been caught.

Now suppose the induction hypothesis that $C(t_n) = Z_n$, and for all $0 \leq t < t_n$ we have $C(t) > Z_n$, and the thief's strategy has produced valid movement up to $\Theta(t_n) = Z_{n+1}$. The thief will now move to the next Zeno point: if $t_n \leq t \leq t_n + 2^{-n-2}$ then $\Theta(t) = Z_{n+1} - (t-t_n)$, ending with $\Theta(t_n + 2^{-n-2}) = Z_{n+2}$. In this same time interval, $C(t) \geq Z_n - (t-t_n) \geq 2^{-n} - 2{-n-2} > 2^{-n-1} = Z_{n+1}$, so the thief is not caught during that time. Then if there is then a time $t_{n+1}$ such that $C(t_{n+1}) = Z_{n+1}$, $t_{n+1} > t_n$ and $|C(t_{n+1})-C(t_n)| \leq t_{n+1}-t_n$ implies $t_{n+1} \geq t_n + Z_n - Z_{n+1} = t_n + 2^{-n-1} > t_n + 2^{-n-2}$, so the thief is already at $\Theta(t_{n+1}) = Z_{n+2}$ and has not been caught before time $t_{n+1}$.

So if the cop visits only a finite number of Zeno points, the thief reaches the first unvisited Zeno point without being caught, moves to the second unvisited Zeno point without being caught, and safely stays there forever. If the cop visits all the Zeno points, the thief can stay "a step ahead" and avoid capture forever.

Supposing there could be a point $t_e$ where $C(t_e) = \Theta(t_e)$ leads to a contradiction: On the closed interval $t \in [0, t_e]$, a continuous function $C$ must attain its minimum: there is at least one time $t_m \leq t_e$ with $C(t) \geq C(t_m)$ whenever $0 \leq t \leq t_e$. Let $Z_n$ be the last Zeno point with $Z_n \geq C(t_m)$. ($n = \lceil - \log_2 C(t_m) \rceil$.) The thief has position $\Theta(t) \leq Z_{n+1}$ whenever $t \geq t_m$. But since $t_e \geq t_m$, this means $\Theta(t_e) \leq Z_{n+1} < C(t_m) \leq C(t_e)$; contradiction.

These Zeno points also hint at an understanding of the problem with the cop's strategy. Claiming "I will certainly catch the thief before time $\frac{2}{3}$" is somewhat like claiming "I can visit all the Zeno points before time $\frac{2}{3}$". But the cop needs to be somewhere at the actual time $t=\frac{2}{3}$, besides the times before that. And a continuous function from closed interval $[0,\frac{2}{3}]$ to a universe $(0,1)$ must attain a minimum within that universe, and so can only visit a finite number of Zeno points. The cop can visit an unlimited number of Zeno points in less than $\frac{2}{3}$ seconds, but can never visit all of them in any duration of time.

Comment: Cop step1: if c(t)≠w(t), move at full speed to the point w(t)/2. Cop step2: Repeat step1. Where's your thief at time 2/3?

Comment: @Eric Where is the cop at t = 2/3?

Comment: @AlexJones That I can't answer, but neither can one answer about the thief. So one cannot claim the thief escapes at time t=2/3 any more than one can claim the cop catches him at t=2/3.

Comment: This argument proves that "the cop can't win" (by catching the thief under the stated conditions), which is true. The thing is, a symmetric argument proves that "the thief can't win" (by evading forever under the conditions).

Comment: If $T$ is any positive real number and $C : [0, T] \to (0,1)$ is any continuous function, then the algorithm I gave describes a continuous function $\Theta : [0,T] \to (0,1)$. Your cop algorithm never describes a continuous function $C : [0, T] \to (0,1)$ if $T \geq \frac{2}{3}$, no matter what $\Theta(t)$ is. So I'd say the thief algorithm is an actual algorithm, and the cop's isn't a complete actionable algorithm.

Comment: But wait, I see it. The thief can likewise only visit finitely many Zeno points in time $[0,1]$, and it certainly is a valid cop movement to visit more Zeno points in a shorter time, then stop.

Comment: The question of reaction is irrelevant. The cop strategy of moving to the left at full speed is optimal. The part saying "until our positions coincide" is not part of the strategy. The strategy can formalized as simply "move left at full speed" without changing anything. So the cop's strategy does not depend on the thief. Likewise the thief strategy can be "move to the left at half speed" without taking any account of what the cop does, and that will avoid the cop, whatever strategy he does, up until t=2/3. So the thief's strategy does not depend on the cop.

Comment: @DJClayworth Except I can't accept simply "move to the left at full/half speed" as even being a strategy, since it doesn't result in a description of position as a function of time.

Comment: It definitely does result in a description of position as a function of time. That's what moving at a constant velocity means.

Comment: @DJClayworth it doesn't, because that function is not a member of the set of possible strategies $\mathcal{F} = \{f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow(0,1)\}$ (this is where well-definedness of the problem comes in. This is how I, and I believe aschepler and obscurans, formalize the definition of "strategy")

Comment: I believe you, like many people, have fallen into the trap of assuming that a "strategy" is a mapping from one position to another. I see nothing to make me think that is true, and it gives rise to several fallacies, including (but not limited to) Zeno's paradox.

Comment: I'm not mapping one position to another. I'm mapping time to position, representing where the agent would be at time t. Regardless of how the agent move, the agent would be at a specific position at time t, this is what the function is mapping. You can think of it as recording the history of the agent's position if you like.

Answer (score 4):

So it looks like the answer is

> The police catches the thief in some time < 2/3

Reasoning

> The thief must slow down because otherwise it would reach 0.  The cop continues at speed one and before 2/3, when he would reach 0, he must overtake the thief as the paradox resolves itself.

Comment: This argument doesn't work: the thief can continue at speed 1/2 for all the time <2/3, following his own strategy if the cop is moving at speed 1, and the cop won't catch him in that time.

Comment: @Randal'Thor but time marches on and at time 2/3, the cop cant be at 0, so must have stopped at the thief's location.

Comment: Why must he have stopped at the thief's location? The thief can always stay closer to 0 than the cop, Zeno-like, following the strategy outlined in the OP.

Comment: At what time must the thief slow down?

Comment: @user253751 the thief is constantly slowing down, approaching 0 speed.  the cop isn't

Comment: @SteveV at what time does the thief begin to slow down?

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on obscuran's answer: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/112389/11569

There is no answer because the game has no equilibrium, as obscuran explains.

**Claim 1. For every fixed thief strategy (i.e. continuous path $f(t)$), there exists a cop strategy that beats it.**

**Claim 2. For every fixed cop strategy (i.e. continuous path $g(t)$), there exists a thief strategy that beats it.**

Proof of Claim 1:
Let $f(t)$ be the thief's strategy. At time $t=2/3$ the thief is at some location $x = f(2/3)$ in $(0,1)$. A winning cop strategy is to travel directly to $x$ by time $t=2/3$, then stay there. The cop can accomplish this continuously at a maximum speed of $1$, and catches the thief at time $t=2/3$ at the latest.

Proof of Claim 2:
Let $g(t)$ be the cop's strategy. At each time $t$, the thief moves to location $g(t)/2$. This is continuous, moves at speed at most $1$ (actually $1/2$), and stays in $(0,1)$ because $g$ does. At all times there is a gap of size $g(t)/2$ between the two, so the thief wins.

*Thanks to obscurans for improving and simplifying both arguments.*

Comment: +1. I think the thief strategy is easier: just use $f(t)=g(t)/2$. $f$ inherits everything from $g$: continuity, domain, max speed 1. The cop also guarantees catching the thief by $t=2/3$ by moving to $f(2/3)$, which takes at most $2/3$ time.

Comment: Thanks @obscurans, both good improvements!

Comment: Except the cop's strategy as described depends on knowing a future property of the thief's movement, which we can't allow. There are ways to fix this, though.

Comment: @aschepler is right. It can be fixed by following the cop's strategy as in the OP: simply travel towards the origin at unit speed. Instead of "catching", just think of whether the cop has passed the thief or not. Let $x > 0$ be the least value of the position of the thief in the time interval $[0,2/3]$ (which exists since it's a closed interval and position is a continuous function). Then, at time $2/3 - x/2$, the cop is at position $0 < x/2 < x$.

Comment: But then, by the intermediate value theorem, the cop should have already crossed the thief at some point in time $< 2/3 - x/2$. Hence, the cop's strategy works against any "fixed" thief strategy.

Comment: @aschepler It depends what you define as a strategy. I let them be continuous functions of $t$ only. If you allow strategies to be functions of the opponents' moves up to current time, I think you need a much more detailed, precise definition of strategy.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know because the problem is not well defined.  We know the cop moves with velocity $-1$ on the time interval $[0,\frac 23)$.  We know the thief moves with velocity $-\frac 12$ on the same interval.  Before $t=\frac 23$ the cop has not caught the thief.  We don't know what to do at the limit because neither one is allowed to move to $0$.  The stated velocities must break down before $t=\frac 23$ but we don't know when or how.

Comment: The problem is perfectly well defined.

Comment: It's the cop's proposed strategy that isn't well defined.

Comment: Hmm, I think you've got a point. Neither the thief or the cop has any reason to change their strategy on the time interval [0,2/3), but their claims can't both be true on that time interval, otherwise we can't consistently claim where they will be at time 2/3. So something must be wrong.

Comment: I agree with this answer. The question doesn't specify what happens at time 1/3 if the thief walk left at speed 1 all the time.

Comment: @Eric, perhaps defining a strategy formally as "a function of time which maps [0,inf) representing time to (0,1) representing position" will make it well defined?

Comment: I believe it is completely acceptable to define a strategy as a mapping from time to velocity.

Answer (score 2):

> The thief cannot be caught.

The optimal strategy for both the cop and the thief is to move in the negative direction at full speed. For these strategies, we have functions  that describe the position of the thief and cop for time t:

$ d_t(t) = 1/3 - t $

$ d_c(t) = 2/3 - t $

However, $d_t(t)$ is not defined for $t>=1/3$. For all $t<1/3$ (the range over which  the problem is defined) $d_t(t) < d_c(t)$. Therefore, the cop cannot catch the thief.

Trying to say that the thief **cannot** continue to execute their strategy of moving in the negative direction at speed 1 would require supposing additional physics not specified in the problem. The situation is comparable to behavior around black holes. From the perspective of an infalling observer, the physics cease being defined beyond the time where the observer would reach the singularity. The situation is the same here. Given the allowed motion and constraints on the physical space, it also serves to constrain the time domain under certain motions.

Comment: I think this is the same as my answer.

Comment: @DJClayworth The same conclusion, yeah. I upvoted your answer, I just thought I'd give explicit equations of motion and direct example of something in real life physics that behaves like this (at least in the math).

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to do something rather weird here, and create a second answer. That's because I want to answer a slightly different variant of the question, and propose a controversial result.

My other answer considers the formulation of the question, and also addresses the case where the endpoints of the universe are "allowed" but are outside the universe. This one specifically considers the case where the endpoints of the universe ($x=0$ and $x=1$) are forbidden to both players.

In that case I believe (controversially)

> The cop will catch the thief.

How do I arrive at this? By simply noting that every point in the universe can be visited by the cop in a finite time $t<2/3$. It doesn't matter that there are an infinite number of points to visit, the cop can still visit them all. Just like they can visit all the points between $x=0.6$ and $x=0.5$ in a tenth of a time unit, even though that is an infinite number of points. (I've neglected the parts of the universe on the right of the cop, where $x>2/3$. We know that the thief can never reach that part of the universe without being caught, because movement is continuous so they would have pass through the cop to reach it, meaning they are caught.)

> If every point that the thief might exist at can be visited in finite time by the cop, the thief will be caught.

But what about the strategies that seem in indicating the thief eternally evading the cop? They are subject to the same fallacies that Zeno's paradox falls to. Zeno says that Achilles cannot catch the tortoise because there is an infinite sequence of steps for him to so so. Likewise the "thief escapes" solution says there are an infinite sequence of steps for the cop to catch the thief. Zeno is wrong because the infinite sequence of steps finishes in a finite time. These strategies are wrong for the same reason. The thief can avoid the cop for an infinite number of steps, but that does not mean he can avoid the cop for an infinite amount of time.

In my other answer I ask what happens at $t=2/3$ (with the thief following his "optimum" strategy). If we impose the restriction that no player may be at $x=0$ then the answer is unknown, but whatever answer it is it doesn't matter. The thief must be at some position $x>0$ but also with a lower x than the cop's starting point (otherwise they are caught), and the cop (as we said) can visit all those positions before $t=2/3$.  If the cop can visit all the possible locations of the thief in finite time then the thief must be caught.

Comment: I guess the real question to make this answer has weight is: what is a function that visits all location x>0 in finite time?

Comment: But thanks to this second answer of yours, I think I realize the actual question by OP boils down to: is there a bijective function from a closed domain to an open codomain? And [the answer is no](https://qr.ae/pGxQt3). So the cop cannot reach all positions x>0 in finite time. Based on this, if we define cop (and thief) possible strategy as all continuous functions such that f(x)>0 for all x, then the cop cannot catch the thief.

Comment: I'm just linking Quora so you can read the proof yourself, though. The website doesn't matter as long as the content is correct. To put the proof simply, a continuous function with a closed domain will have a maximum and minimum value, but an open interval codomain doesn't have maximum and minimum value (Weierstrass). So the cop cannot possibly visit all positions in (0,1) in finite time while disregarding the thief position. (OTOH, for any function f modeling the thief strategy, the cop can always find a function that approaches 0 "faster", so catches it, but also vice versa)

Comment: I don't think Quora is a good reference. And I'm not sure that proves that the cop cannot visit all the points in a finite time. What's wrong with the function x = 2/3 - t over the range 0 < t < 2/3

Comment: Now that's where the non-well-definedness of the question comes in. The current question doesn't formally define what a strategy is. If we formally define "strategy" as "a function from [0,inf) to (0,1)", then $f=2/3-t$ is not a valid strategy since it maps x=2/3 to outside the range (0,1).

Comment: You have fallen into the trap, like others, of thinking that a "strategy" means defining the "next" point to move to rather than a mapping from t to x or just a mapping from t to v.

Comment: Um, didn't I just define a strategy as a function from [0,inf) to (0,1)? I meant that as a function of time. So with strategy f, at time x, the position would be at f(x). (perhaps my typo of x=2/3 instead of t=2/3 misled you, my bad). To clarify, when I said mapping from a closed interval, I meant it as an interval of time, since we are discussing about finite time. In all of my correspondences above, I never talk about mapping from a position to a next position, always from time to position.

Comment: Just because you chose to use that definition doesn't mean it's the right one. Maybe you should explain what your "strategy functions" actually map from and to as variables, rather than just what the ranges of the variables are. I dispute that a "strategy function" has to specify a position as an output. Specifying a velocity is perfectly acceptable. I think it's up to you to show that the functions you choose are the only acceptable forms of strategy.

Comment: It's the straightforward one, the strategy is defined as where the agent will be at time t. Considering the set of function $f(t)$ that maps to velocity like you mention is also acceptable, under the condition that the cumulative distance $F(t)$ doesn't lie outside the range $(0,1)$, which is equivalent to specifying position.

Comment: Btw, I think we should make sure we are at the same page first. As noted by aschepler in another comment, you seem to understand my definition (and aschepler and obscurans) as defining "the next position to move to"? If so, let me try to clarify, as it's not that. A strategy is defined as a function of time f(t), specifying where the agent will be at position t. This essentially define the trajectory of the agent through time. (also, if that matter, I respect you in other stack exchange sites, you have been an excellent contributor. Perhaps we should take a break and come back to this later?)

Comment: I understand that you are trying to define a strategy as "x a function of time". It is your chosen definition of strategy that is leading you to the (incorrect) conclusion that the thief will escape. You are essentially forcing the cop (and the thief) to specify limits to their strategies, i.e. in terms of "where will I stop before hitting the wall". Neither needs to actually do that. If you chose a different definition of "strategy" you would reach a different conclusion I believe. So your conclusion is a function of your choice, not of the puzzle.

Comment: The reason we focus so much on "position as a function of time" isn't so much related to a "strategy". That's the only way a point-like entity can exist at all in a universe that has time and position, no matter what causes for that position there may or may not be.

Comment: Would your reasoning be the same for this version of the problem? Both live in a universe $(1,\infty)$. But the maximum speed one can travel depends on current position $x$, specifically $|v| \leq x^2$. The thief is at $x=3$, and the cop is at $x=\frac{3}{2}$. The cop can still reach any point in the universe within time $\frac{2}{3}$. But the thief can just move to the right at the current max speed of the cop, always keeping distance $1$ ahead of the cop. This is actually the same problem, just with variables changed.

Comment: As I say elsewhere, what is the problem with defining a strategy as "x = 2/3 - t for 0 >= x < 2/3"? Fully defined and visits every point in the universe.

Comment: So at and after time $\frac{2}{3}$, the cop just doesn't exist, or what? This seems like a violation of the rule that he "live in an open interval $(0,1)$". But if that's a possibility, then the thief can likewise be at $x = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{t}{2}$ for $0 \leq t < \frac{2}{3}$, and the cop never catches the thief.

Comment: Or actually, what's then the issue with the thief's strategy being $x=\frac{1}{3}$ for $0 \leq t < 0.01$? Then the cop will certainly never catch the thief.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the cop is after that. He can go and get a cup of tea. However  for the previous interval the thief must have been at one of the points that the cop visited, and so will be in jail.

Comment: No - for those specific two functions, find the exact time the cop catches the thief by being at the same position. There isn't one.

Comment: The question isn't "What time does the cop catch the thief", it's "does the cop catch the thief".

Comment: "The cop catches the thief if cop position=thief position." That's never true, therefore the cop does not catch the thief.

Comment: Backtrack. Your "thief strategy" is incomplete. Where does the thief go after that? He doesn't cease to exist. My cop strategy has an implicit "and at t=2/3 and after can go wherever he likes because he has already caught the thief".

Comment: Any attempt to extend that cop's function to time $t=\frac{2}{3}$, not to mention beyond, will violate the word "continuously" in the original statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131091/discussion-between-djclayworth-and-aschepler).

Comment: also, Eric the OP has clarified the right definition of strategy [in this comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112368/can-the-cop-catch-the-thief?noredirect=1#comment317408_112368), which is the same as the function I noted above.

Answer (score 2):

The thief will be caught.

The cop simply moves at his maximum speed towards 0 *until he catches the thief*.

The thief is constantly going to retreat, certainly, and has an infinite number of positions to move to before 0 - but sometime prior to, and almost exactly, t=2/3, the cop will have checked every infinitely possible position and *has* to have found the thief by the time t=2/3 - but will not catch the thief in any specifiable time frame prior to t=2/3